# Testing regex with Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regex and I'm using the following code snippet for testing purpose:

```
String regex = "";
String test = "";
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(test).find();
```

but when I try some like this:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("h{2,4}").matcher("hhhhh").find());
```

it returns true and not false as expected.

or

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("h{2}").matcher("hhh").find());
```

it returns true and not false as expected.

What's the problem? Maybe this is not the right statements to use for testing correctly the regex?

thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The string `hhh` contains two `h`s, therefore the regex matches since the `find()` method allows matching of substrings.

If you anchor the regex to force it to match the entire string, the regex will fail:

```
^h{2}$
```

Another possibility would be to use the `matches()` method:

```
"hhh".matches("h{2}")
```

will fail.

Comment: ah I should have just comment on your question to talk about matches instead of writting my own.

Answer (score 1):

But this won't return `true`.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("^h{2,4}$").matcher("hhhhh").find());
```

`^` is the beginning of the line

`$` is the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [.matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) and not .find(). You should also anchor it like @Tim said.